# Some words missing when editing a post in Stack Overflow

Tags: support, bug, status-bydesign, stack-overflow, quality-filter

I try to edit a question [how to find the commit message by author?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4309674/how-to-find-the-commit-message-by-author)

In the question a word "hello" is there.

> [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1wLNb.jpg]

But in the edit the word is not appearing.

> [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NxXU5.jpg]

An extra word `[git]` is also appearing in title of edit area.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The "hello" is being removed automatically, there's [a filter that removes silly stuff](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/93989/162704) like that. The filter runs both when you first submit the question and when you edit it, the reason that "hello" wasn't removed in the question in question is because it was originally posted on Nov 30 '10, which is *before* the filter was implemented.

No idea about `[git]` in the title.

Comment: looks like tag fetched in ..title ...

Comment: We also strip out things from the title that look like tags. Not sure how it works, exactly, but in this case the match is exact. The original title of the post included `[git]`. We just don't show it when displaying the question, apparently. Pretty sure that feature went in after Nov 30 2010, so I'm inclined to blame the age of the question for that too.

Comment: Fun fact: couldn't get rid of the "hello" by submitting an empty edit. Thankfully (?) the whole body of the question needed improvement.